# Why TypeScript toString method is not invoked as desired

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a pretty simple code.

There is a model with `toString` overwritten:

policy.ts:

```
export class Policy {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;

  toString(): string {
    return this.name + ': ' + this.description;
  }
}
```

Then I use the `Policy` model in two ways.

binding to `create-policy.component.html`:

```
...
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="policy.name" required>
```

and it in the component `create-policy.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Policy } from '../models/policy';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-create-policy',
    templateUrl: './create-policy.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create-policy.component.css'],
})
export class CreatePolicyComponent implements OnInit {
    policy: Policy = {
        id: 0,
        name: '',
        description: '',
    };
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
    onSubmitPostHttp() {
        console.log('Started onSubmitPostHttp');
        console.log('policy=' + this.policy.toString());
    }
}
```

Still on the console I do not get properties; it prints:

> create-policy.component.ts:23 policy=[object Object]

Direct logging properties works properly:

```
 console.log("policy=" + this.policy.name);
```

That prints:

> policy=ss

Comment: How is `this.policy` set?

Comment: So you can deduce that this.policy isn't an instance of Policy. Case solved.

Comment: added the code for policy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`policy` isn't an instance of `Policy` and still uses native `toString` method.

The fact that `Policy` class is used as interface like `policy: Policy` doesn't instantiate it. Since plain object conforms to this interface (it already has `toString` method), this doesn't cause type error.

It can be:

```
policy = Object.assign(new Policy, {
  id: 0,
  name: "",
  description: ""
});
```

At this point it becomes obvious that `Policy` class wasn't designed for what it's used, it's better to move property initialization to its constructor:

```
export class Policy {
  constructor(
   public id: number,
   public name: string,
   public description: string
 ) {}

 toString(): string {
   return this.name + ': ' + this.description;
 }

}
```

and

```
policy = new Policy(
  id: 0,
  name: "",
  description: ""
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are creating this.policy as a new object without overriding the toString() method. And that is why it still uses the default implementation when logging the result.

Look at the generated javascript code when creating a typescript class:

**TS Code:**

```
export class Policy {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public description: string;

    toString(): string {
        return this.name + ': ' + this.description;
    }
}

let pol: Policy = {
    id: 0,
    name: "",
    description: ""
};
```

**JS Code:**

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Policy = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Policy() {
        }
        Policy.prototype.toString = function () {
            return this.name + ': ' + this.description;
        };
        return Policy;
    }());
    exports.Policy = Policy;
    var pol = {
        id: 0,
        name: "",
        description: ""
    };
});
```

As you can see here, the toString() method is added to the prototype of the Policy object. There are alot you can read about [prototypes in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) but the key thing here is that the prototype for the policy does not get called unless you use the new operator.

As estus mentioned; all objects in javascript has a toString method, [it is included in the object prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype). That is the reason why you are not getting any errors when creating your object directly, it has all the correct properties and methods for a policy object and that is why typescript allow this behaviour.